# 3D rotation minimizing the distance between 2D points and 3D projected points: closed-form formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, closed-form, 3d, rotations

I know there is a closed-form formula to bring together two sets of 3D points. Is there also a closed-form formula when one set of points is 2D and the other is projected?

More formaly, let $\left(\mathbf{x}_i\right)_n\in\mathbf{R}^{3\times n}$ and $\left(\mathbf{y}_i\right)_n\in\mathbf{R}^{2\times n}$ be two sequences of length $n$ of resp. 3D and 2D points.

I am looking for a closed-form solution for the 3D rotation $R^*\in SO(3)$ and translation $\mathbf{t}^*\in\mathbf{R}^3$ so that
\begin{eqnarray}
(R^*, \mathbf{t}^*) = \arg\min_{R, t} \sum_{i=1}^n \left\|\mathbf{y}_i - (PR\mathbf{x}_i + \mathbf{t})\right\|^2,
\end{eqnarray}
where $P\in\mathbf{R}^{2\times 3}$ is a $2\times 3$ projection matrix that can be assumed to be of rank 2.

Comment: unicity of the solution is not guaranteed

Comment: Yes, at least because of the translation in the direction of the projection -- any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

let $x_1=(1,0,1), x_2=(-1,0,-1), y_1=(1,0), y_2=(-1,0)$
$$P = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1& 0}$$
$$R_1=\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0& 1}$$
$$R_1=\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
-1 & 0& 0}$$

$$\forall i,j \in \{1,2\},  PR_ix_j=y_j$$

Therefore even the unicity of $R$ is not guaranteed

Comment: Yes, there are degenerate cases of course -- as for the "simple" 3D/3D point cloud matching. This is not necessarily a problem. For example, the solution for the 3D/3D case relies on an SVD decomposition -- which is indeed not unique in the general case, even though I would argue this is still a closed-form formula. In practice the non-unicity is usually not a problem when point clouds are large and complex enough.